# Suddenly unable to access resources (drawable)

Tags: android, embedded-resource

I have been running the code fine for days with the animations I was using working perfectly, then today I loaded the project and received an error (bottom) and I'm unable to access the resources.

This is where I'm calling the resource:

```
Bitmap idleImg = bf.decodeResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.spider);
```

Where the Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT is:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class Constants {
   //
    public static Context CURRENT_CONTEXT;
}
```

This is the error that's showing on run now:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72520Library'.
>
> Could not expand ZIP
>
> 'D:\build-tools\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.2.0\appcompat-v7-25.2.0.aar'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that doing 'Run Tests'(even if there are none included) then changing back to normal seems to fix the problem, I'm unsure of the reason why it fixes it but it worked in my case.